# Why does OWASP modsecurity block remote file inclusion for ?& in URL for Rule 950119

Tags: apache, mod-security

[OWASP modsecurity](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/owasp-modsecurity-crs/blob/master/base_rules/modsecurity_crs_40_generic_attacks.conf) rule 950119 for Remote File inclusion blocks the following URL:

```
https://mydomain.com?myparam=http://mysite.com?&param2=abcd
```

What's the issue with having `?&` in an URL causing it to block `?`?

Comment: & is not the issue here. If you take a look at the regex of this rule at https://github.com/SpiderLabs/owasp-modsecurity-crs/blob/master/base_rules/modsecurity_crs_40_generic_attacks.conf#L159, it is only searching for ? after the protocol and domain name. It is searching these in a ARGS variable which include the GET and POST variables. Domain names in either of the variables mean RFI in most of the cases that is why it is detecting those.

Comment: Then why it doesn't block when i have ?myparam=http://mysite.com&param2=abcd